# What is the meaning of "this joke made us cancer"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is means this sentence?

> This joke made us cancer

I had got that comment, but I don't know what is meant for (I think it is idiom)!

Comment: Can you provide more context? Or a link to where it was found? As it stands, it doesn't really seem to me to have much meaning. It could be a poorly written sentence (or joke) by someone who does not know English very well.

Comment: It is just a comment for my posted joke !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to the meme: "X gave Y cancer"

RELATED: [That Post Gave Me Cancer](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/that-post-gave-me-cancer)

> is an image macro series commonly used in response to nonsensical or insubstantial posts submitted by the original poster (OP) or other users in a given thread. This hyperbolic expression implies that the content in question was so far below one’s expectation that it infected the reader with “cancer”, a slang term that is typically used to express one’s disgust towards a trend or a thread.

[image]

I've seen the "X gave Y cancer" meme used to provide ridicule, sarcasm, or sometimes just fun/comical effect.

Comment: I'm glad somebody answered this. The original question made zero sense to me, and I haven't seen this meme. (I'm glad I haven't seen it).

Comment: @ColinFine Different circles tend to use different memes. Reddit's /r/AdviceAnimals has a pretty different set than 4chan.

Comment: +10 If OP confirms this. This did not occur to me at all. It really makes sense.